# Mashery IODocs - Latency issue due to heavy json config file

Tags: json, node.js, iodocs, mashery

Mashery IOdocs is a really a great tools for documenting API.
I'm using it for a quite big project with more then 50 methods and complex structures sent to this API, so that my json config file is more than 4000 lines long.
I self-host IOdocs on a VPS along with other stuff and the doc is awfully slow because of my long json file.
Any idea to cope with this latency ? Except obviously split my json config file into several.

Comment: Is it a latency in rendering the page and/or processing a request? I suspect its the former and indeed, the template could use some refactoring. I'll mock up a huge JSON config and try profiling it. Of course, any ideas on other approaches are welcome and I'd be happy to help rev on those improvements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Just for displaying method's list it takes about 15-20s ... Each requests take almost the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [fork](https://github.com/mikeralphson/iodocs) of IO Docs with some performance improvements which may help. In this instance they involve stripping out json-minify (which is only used to allow comments in the source specifications), server-side cacheing of the specifications and not having to load the specification via a synchronous AJAX call on the client.